# microtasks and event loop

Tags: flutter, dart

The dart documentation says that if the Future is completed, then the then methods will be run in one of the following microtasks. In the following example, everything works as expected because await is applied.

```
// print: exit_main, micro, then
main() async {
  var p = Future.value(1);
  await p;

  scheduleMicrotask(() {
    print('micro');
  });

  p.then((e) {
    print('then');
  });

  print('exit_main');
}
```

But if await is removed, then the logic described above does not work. A microtask that is created before the then function is run after the then function is executed. But the then function is run after main, you can see that because a message is printed at the end of the main function.

```
// print: exit_main, then, micro
main() {
  var p = Future.value(1);

  scheduleMicrotask(() {
    print('micro');
  });

  p.then((e) {
    print('then');
  });

  print('exit_main');
}
```

In connection with what has been said, the following question. Why does the then function run before the created microtask?

Case 2 was expected to work just like the first case when await is applied.

Answer (score 1):

Understood, no answer needed. Presumably, the Future.value function with a simple value completes the Future in the future microtask, i.e. the Future is scheduled to complete before another microtask is called. After the Future completes, all then methods are called immediately, provided that they return a non-terminated Future. The behavior changes if the future has already completed. An example is presented below.

```
main() {
  var p = Future.value(1);

  Timer.run(() {
    scheduleMicrotask(() {
      print('micro');
    });

    p.then((e) {
      print('then');
    });

    print('exit_main');
  });
}
```